# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] or window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing JavaScript that will be used in a `<script>` tag that needs to access the referer URL, and I am thinking of either passing the page URL to the JavaScript via JavaScript, or getting the referer URL via PHP. My problem is that PHP.net says this about `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`...

> Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify `HTTP_REFERRER` as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

However, I believe that JavaScript can also modify `window.location.href`.

So my question is:

Between PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and JavaScript's `window.location.href`, which is more trustworthy/reliable. And/or is there a better way to get a referrer URL this way?

Comment: bottom line is there is no method that's 100% foolproof.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and `window.location.href` won't get you a referrer unless you explicitly pass the value of `window.location.href` as a parameter to your next request.

As for which is better, it depends on what you are doing. If you are making a analytics tracker, `window.location.href` is more-reliable, but requires JavaScript be enabled. If you are using it for CORF protection, definitely use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (in addition to other, more-reliable validation).

Comment: Yes I would be passing the value to the script if I were to use `window.location.href`, and I'd just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` if not. So in this case would it be better to use `window.location.href` passed to the script and maybe `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as a fallback?

Comment: @Coffee'dUpHacker Yes, that's what I would do.